# Distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose there is a p.d.f. $f(x)$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
If we want to compute 
$$g(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [x-a]^+ f(x) dx ,$$
is it possible for to write $g(a)$ as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$?
Currently I can obtain
$$ g(a)=\int_{a}^{+\infty} (x-a) f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx - a \int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x)dx \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=\mu-\int_{-\infty}^{a}xf(x)dx-aF(a) $$

Answer (score 1):

Not only can this not be expressed as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, but for any value of $a$ greater than or equal to $\mu$ you can't even find a positive lower bound for $g(a)$ if $a\ge\mu$.  Just take a distribution on 3 points, one of which is $\mu$ and the other of which are symmetric about $\mu$, with equal probabilities assigned to the extreme points.  Let those extreme points fly off to infinity while holding $\sigma$ (and obviously $\mu$) constant.  g(a) will tend toward 0 for all a, since the probability of being at the positive extreme point has to decrease quadratically to keep the variance constant, and the integrand in the definition of $g$ is merely linear.

A fun exercise would be to find an upper bound for $g(a)$ given $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $X$ to be $N(0,1)$ and $Y=\sqrt {12} (U-\frac 1 2)$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Both have mean 0 and variance 1. The values of $g(0)$ for these two random variables are different. Hence $g$ cannot be expressed as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.